# How to get 302 HTTP response header in angularjs $http success callback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, http-headers

I want to get `Location` header value(**302 HTTP redirect**) within an API call success callback. I have tried `headers('Location')` but `console.log()` shows `null`. how can I fetch response headers properly?

**Response Headers :**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:324
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 15 Oct 2015 18:51:04 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Location:http://localhost/redirect --------------- Redirect Uri
Server:Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12
```

**Angular success callback :**

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    window.location.href = headers('Location');
})
```

Comment: @KateMihalikova this is not my Q

Comment: As XMLHttpRequest (used by angular) transparently follows redirects, there is no way to get a `Location` header from first (= different) response headers, as you can read there.

Comment: @KateMihalikova thanx, after some research I concluded that you are right lady :)